# RoR - Matrix-like chart for categorical data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plot

I would like to plot some data, where the y-axis represents cars, the x-axis a certain property, and now each car, for a certain property could take one of three values (yes,no,average), so something like this:

```
              C1 | yes | no | average | no
              C2 | no  | no | yes     | yes
              C3 | yes | yes| no      | average
                 | P1  | P2 | P3      | P4
```

Is there a tool I could use for something like that? I usually use highcharts for plotting graphs.. but I don't think highcharts will be able to plot something like that..

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used it personally, but a search for "rails pivot table gem" produced this page, amongst others: http://itshouldbeuseful.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/easy-grid-tables-and-forms-using-pivot_table/

You might also search for `crosstab`